# Single use tags and synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags

We had a great grand opening, now we need to work on cleaning up all of the confetti on the floor. If you have a few minutes, please take a look at [where single use tags begin](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags?page=3) and work your way to the end.

What I'd like to do is start a discussion to address the following:

- Are any of the single use tags `meta` tags? I.e. do they fail to describe the content of the question?
- Do several tags overlap? If so, which one should be the primary tag and which ones should be synonyms?
- Are any of the tags too localized? I.e. not likely to be used ever again?

I'm hoping that we can address this now, rather than later while its still a relatively easy task to accomplish. I'm also wondering if some of our [unanswered questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered) might receive more attention if they were tagged better.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few to kick things off... I've made this CW; please add to it!

Meta (tags, not site)

- website
- www
- best-practice
- webmaster

Synonyms

- https,  ssl, tls (close enough)
- certificate, ssl-certificate
- cdn, content-delivery-network
- browser, browsers
- static, static-content
- url, urls
- user, users
- poll, visitor-poll
- ab-testing, a-b-testing

Is synonym management available on the SE sites yet?

Comment: Yes, you can find the synonyms tool in the 'links' tab of the moderator tool section, but I don't think Jeff's new super spiffy tag obliterator 9000 unit will show up for a while.